# How to recognize that system date was changed (manually or automatically)?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app that saves some data when system date changes.
I tried to use a BroadcastReceiver to receive the Intent `android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED`, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Here is my code for the Receiver:

```
public class BroadcastDateChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED")) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Date changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastDateChangedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When I change the system date (either manually or it changes automatically) the Toast doesn't appear.

What is wrong with my code?
Should I use a different approach to determine a system date change?

Answer (score 0):

This bug is obsolete. See this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2880) 
Some research and variants in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758246/android-action-date-changed-broadcast)