# Android Date Changed Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a broadcast receiver that receives event when user manually changes Date . But I am unable to find what was the previous date he changed. Example- If date was 5-June-2014 and he changed it to 01-June-2014. I want to know the previous date that is 5-june-2014. Please help

Comment: android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED is the intent for date changed.

Comment: For that you would have to keep running a service every minute or so and updating the time to a value in the sharedpreference.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i want to know the previous date that user has changed, is there any property or method that i can use in Broadcast receiver that tells what was the date that user changed ?

Comment: You would have to keep saving the time value every minute and when the broadcast reciever, sends you signal of time changed, then in your handler action, you would have to get the last saved time in sharedpreference and do necessary action with it. Hope you can understand what i am trying to communicate.

Comment: I've made a full sample of this exactly, including telling you what was the previous date it was on, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48782963/878126

Answer (score 0):

You could register `ACTION_TIME_TICK` and record the current date every minute.