# Android check for date changed

Tags: java, c#, android, date, xamarin

I'm trying to update my Android app based on the date.

So, for example, if it's a certain date show some information about that date.

Or,  when it's a new week, do a couple of things in the background.

How do I do this?

Do I check constantly for the date? Is there a "`flag`" when the date has changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use brodcast receiver like ACTION_DATE_CHANGED

More details can be found at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED

**Answer to more questions:**

1) For specific date you can have check within onReceive method.
2) To schedule it at a different time or do other stuffs after particular days, you can also use Alarm Service like in the below link:

[Android - How to set a notification to a specific date in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017943/android-how-to-set-a-notification-to-a-specific-date-in-the-future)

Comment: Thanks. But how do I check for a specific date? Should I just do an if statement inside onReceive? Also, how do I check for a new week? And, is there an option to check at a different time than midnight?

Comment: Answer update. Accept as answer if it helps you so that other can also use the same answer. Cheers!

Comment: @amitairos Try the code I've made here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48782963/878126 . For special date checks, you can use the LocalDate that you receive. It has plenty of functions.

Comment: `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` will be called only when you change the date manually from settings. If date is changed automatically by the clock, so from 23:59 -> 00:00 than this will not be called.